# Array slice like hash slice in perl

Tags: php

Is there built-in function, or shorter way to extract elements into new array, as described here?

```
<?php

function arr_slice ($arr, $keys) {
  $ret = array();
  foreach ($keys as $k) { $ret[$k] = $arr[$k]; }

  return $ret;
}

$array = array(
  "a" => 1,
  "b" => 2,
  "c" => 3,
  "d" => 4,
);
var_export(
  arr_slice($array, array("x","d","b"))
);
```

output (key order matters)

```
array (
  'x' => NULL,
  'd' => 4,
  'b' => 2,
)
```

Comment: One thing is that this code gives a notice as 'x' is an undefined index, may be worth changing to `$arr[$k]??null` if PHP 7+.

Comment: @NigelRen yes, or `isset($arr[$k]) ? $arr[$k] : null` for older versions.